# Normalising Constant for exponentiated function

Tags: normal-distribution, normalization, bounds, exponential-family, gumbel-distribution

What would the normalising  constant be of the following, or atleast an approximation? I would like to avoid sampling.

$$f(\theta)=\exp(-k_1e^{-k_2\theta^2}-\theta^2)\qquad\theta\in(-\infty,\infty), \quad k_1,k_2>0$$

In the event that its not possible, what would be a valid **polynomial** lower bound on $\log(f(\theta))$, that would take into account $k_1$

For anyone, who is interested, I end up with this expresssion because I place a Gaussian prior over (a squared exponential) kernel parameters, and trying to use variational bayes (hence, a lower bound).

Comment: A substitution like $U = \Theta^2$ gets something that looks like a negative fractional moment of a [Gumbel type I](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-1_Gumbel_distribution), which is probably no use. Nevertheless, that same transformation might help in identifying good bounds.

Comment: @Glen_b Finding a polynomial bound for the logarithm of $f(\theta)$ is simple: the best possible one that is valid for all $\theta$ is $-k_1 - \theta^2.$ That follows from three observations: (1) $f(\theta)$ is symmetric about $0,$ (2) $\log(f(0))=-k_1,$ and (3) $\log(f(\theta))$ is asymptotically $-\theta^2.$

Comment: @whuber Good point. I was so focused on trying to find a normalizing constant I wasn't even thinking about just trying to look for a bound right off.